# How to do this box copy overlay effect in CSS?

Tags: css

I want to create this dialog window in CSS:

[image]

The only way I managed to come close to this was to copy the dialog window several times, tilt it with `transform: rotate(..)` and play a bit with z-indexes.

Could this be achieved with borders or box shadows without having to copy the original dialog window? It doesn't have to literally be there three times, of course. It can just be an illusion.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that with just borders and shadows, no.

Comment: Couldn't you just right click and *"Inspect Element"* to find out?

Comment: @PeterKrebs It's from Adobe XD and the designer used some sort of polygon.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59082521/8620333

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you'd be able to do it with just borders, though you could use pseudo-elements to avoid actually having to copy the element and some Z transforms to achieve this:

```css
#modal, #modal:before, #modal:after{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #eee;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute; 
}
#modal:before{
  transform: rotate(-3deg) translateZ(-1px);
}
#modal:after{
  transform: rotate(-6deg) translateZ(-2px);
}
#modal{
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto; 
}
```

```html
<div id='modal'></div>
```

This basically creates two pseudo-copies of your modal and pushes them behind the original with slightly different rotation.

Comment: Since the pseudo elements have almost identical css, it is better to declare a common rule for both `#modal:before, #modal:after {...transform: rotate(-3deg) translateZ(-1px); ...}`. Then override the different css for `#modal:after { z-index: -2; transform: rotate(-6deg) translateZ(-2px); }`

Comment: True! I'll update the answer!